# User Interface Problems - CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm currently working on a flash project using external interface and I'm able to get this [interface to display](http://codepen.io/rginnow/pen/mwFpC). However when I try to type something in the input field, it doesn't allow me to click on the field or on the buttons. So I did some digging around and found out that maybe this is what's causing it.

```
  .panel {
    background: #000;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 45%;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: -1;
  }
```

I tried changing `z-index` to `1` and it allowed me to type but at the same time, it seems to mess up the interface. Does anyone have a fix for this?

One more thing, whenever I click on a option like `change password` the panel opens up, but when I click on it again, it doesn't close but instead slides right back up.

I'm no expert when it comes to CSS so I'm hoping someone can help me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `z-index: -1` from class .panel and add `z-index: 1` to class .options.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MymbOg)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Thanks a lot mate!

Comment: Any way to fix the second issue of the panel sliding back upon clicking the button instead of closing?

Comment: I updated CodePen. Idea - when div "opens up" add class active and on close check if div is active. (It's better to add class "active" on animate complete, but for this I left as it is). Also You need to handle what happens if user clicks another div to open (how to close previously opened and so on..)

Answer (score 0):

The **z-index** should stack with **position:relative or position:absolute**,
and you can try to make it to z-index:999 or make the other div contain in your html to z:index:-1;

Answer (score 0):

you have additional classes on the sliding panels to the right

You need to change the z-index on these panels when they slide right
Add z-index=1 When you password panel slides right and remove it when it slides back to the left

Answer (score 0):

The issue is although you get the panel displayed via `left:51%;`
but it still have 'z-index:-1;' but when you give it `z-index:1;` its overlap the button

The solution is to give the panel `display:none;` and toggle it on click the button and hence you could use `z-index:1;`

check out the new [copepen](http://codepen.io/w34/pen/QNvGaP)